# How can I fix "Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors." when i'm working with perl one-liners

Tags: perl

I'm writing a program in Perl, which is running on MobaXterm. My problem is that I want a Perl to run a Perl one-liner (which is piped with another unix command). My one-liner works fine, when I just type it in the terminal, but I can't seem to make it work through Perl.

My command as it works in the terminal is

```
samtools view $file.bam | 
perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ m/NM:i:(\d+)/) {print $1, "chr(10)"}' > $file.nm
```

I test my program with the file `'M1.10.fasta'`

I have copied my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $read1 = 'Intesti-cocktail_R1.fastq'; 
my $read2 = 'Intesti-cocktail_R2.fastq'; 
my $dir = '/home/local1/balin/TestData/'; 

chdir($dir) or die "no dir"; #change directory 
opendir(DIR, '.') or die "no dir"; 
my @filelist = readdir(DIR); 
closedir(DIR); 

@filelist = grep(m/^M\d+\.\d+\.fasta$/, @filelist); # clean list of unwanted names


foreach my $file (@filelist) {
    my $cmd1 = "bwa index $file";
    my $cmd2 = "bwa mem $file $read1 $read2 | samtools view -Sb - > $file.bam"; 
    my $cmd3 = "samtools view $file.bam | perl -ne \"if ($_ =~ m/NM:i:(\\d+)/) {print $1, 'chr(10)'}\" > $file.nm";
    my $returnvalue1 = system($cmd1);
    my $returnvalue2 = system($cmd2);
    my $returnvalue3 = system($cmd3);
    print "Failed command1 ($returnvalue1): $cmd1\n" if $returnvalue1 != 0;
    print "Failed command2 ($returnvalue2): $cmd2\n" if $returnvalue2 != 0; 
    print "Failed command3 ($returnvalue3): $cmd3\n" if $returnvalue3 != 0;
}
```

My error messages are:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at Perl_BWAv2.pl line 21.
Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at Perl_BWAv2.pl line 21.
syntax error at -e line 1, near "( =~"
syntax error at -e line 1, near ";}"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
Failed command3 (65280): samtools view M1.10.fasta.bam | perl -ne 'if ( =~ m/NM:i:(\d+)/) {print , "(10)"}' > M1.10.fasta.nm
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the variables in your perl command so they aren't interpolated:

```
my $cmd3 = qq{samtools view $file.bam | perl -ne "if (\$_ =~ m/NM:i:(\\d+)/) {print \$1, 'chr(10)'}" > $file.nm};
#                                                      ^                             ^
```

However, I would recommend against spawning a new perl process, since it makes for easier debugging when you do things within your current perl script:

```
open my $AM, '-|', 'samtools', 'view', "$file.bam" or die "Can't open samtools: $!";
open my $outfh, '>', "$file.nm" or die "Can't open $file.nm: $!";
while (<$AM>) {
    print $outfh $1, 'chr(10)' if m/NM:i:(\d+)/;
}
close $outfh;
```

Comment: Also, using `open my $AM, '-|', 'samtools', 'view', "$file.bam"` etc. might prevent the need to call Perl from Perl.

Comment: @choroba Alternative approach added.  Works?

Comment: As far as I can guess, it should :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your perl code, you are enclosing the commands for perl to run in double quotes instead of single quotes; shells treat the two quite differently, and unless you are using shell variables, you should stick to single quotes.  Revert to single quotes, and escape the $'s that you don't intent your perl script to interpolate:

```
my $cmd3 = "samtools view $file.bam | perl -ne 'if (\$_ =~ m/NM:i:(\\d+)/) {print \$1, \"chr(10)\"}/ > $file.nm";
```

It always helps to print what you are feeding to system or a pipe-open, too.